# Button isn't working at all

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, html

I am making a program that has an array of numbers and then the user inputs some values in and clicks on verify. the value he enters has to be in order with the array of numbers and if it isn't the user gets an alert message sorry.

The value inside the first input bar decides from which number of the array should the comparison should start. For example, if the array holds numbers like {2,4,6,8,10} and the user enters 6 in the first input bar and then he enters 8 and 10 in the next two bars, he should get the result "678" 
If he doesn't get the first number right lets say he enters 3, and since 3 isn't in the array, then it doesn't matter what he enters in the other input bars, he would get the result "Sorry".

Similarly, if the user types 4 in the first input bar but then then in the second bar he types 8, he should still get the result "Sorry" since the order of the array is {4,6,8} not {4,8}.

I made a program but whenever I click on the verify button, nothing happens.

Here is my codes. and here is also the result I am getting: 
https://jsfiddle.net/53j19rpt/

```
<html>

<head>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var arr = [];
    var t;
    var num = 2;
    var x = [];
    for (var x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
        document.getElementById("one" + x);
    }

    function go() {
        for (var t = 0; t < 4; k++) {
            x[t] = num * (t + 1);
        }
        for (var k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
            if (document.getElementById("one0").value >= x[k])
                if (document.getElementById("one" + k).value == x[k])
                    document.write(document.getElementById("one" + k).value);
                else
                    document.write("Sorry");
        }
    }
</script>

<body>
    <input id="one0" type="text">
    <input id="one1" type="text">
    <input id="one2" type="text">
    <input id="one3" type="text">
    <input type="button" id="verifyBtn" value="verify" onclick="go()">
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You can NEVER use document.write after page load. And you need to wait for load to access fields on the page

Comment: what is the purpose of for (var x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
        document.getElementById("one" + x);
    } ??

Comment: I actually gave up trying to fix this. `document.getElementById("one" + x);` is not complete and not needed where it is. Please use better variable names. `i` is almost universally used in a for loop, but you have t and k and not consistently updating them. You risk running a perpetual loop when updating k in more than one place and the var is being hoisted too

Comment: Sorry abt that.. I was planning on making something else but then erased it but i forgot to erase that useless part.. Ok so all i need to do is use window.onload? And thats it?

Comment: No other error?

Comment: `for (var t = 0; t < 4; k++) ` : wrong loop, loop has variable `t` and you're incrementing `k` making the loop infinite

Comment: Oh yeaa my mistake oops.. So these r the 2 errors right? Will the program work after i fix these?

Comment: Here is what I THINK you want: https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/amnc9zLw/

Comment: @mplungjan, how did you get rid of `go is not defined` error  ?

Comment: I changed the fiddle to "In Head" - I also posted the code here after changing it

Comment: It works better thanks but the thing is, the array is {2,4,6,8}, so even if the user inputs 4 in the first bar but then enters 6,8 in the next and clicks verify, it should say correct..

Comment: Same goes for if he enters 6.. if the next input has the value 8.. he should get the result correct

Comment: Also, i am gonna make this thing that the user is gonna type in the number of bars he wants to see and then based on that the input bars will appear but yea i know how to do that

Comment: @mplungjan, it may be a silly question, but can you tell me how did re positioning the script rectify the error ?

Comment: In the fiddle, I clicked on the (Javascript) button and changed to "in head" so the function was defined before using it

Comment: @BuffyAnne-summers - have a look at my second attempt. I am still not 100% sure what you are trying

Comment: And the third too. I will sign off and turn off my computer

Answer (score 0):

Version 1 - all 4 have to be correct in order

```js
var x = [],num=2;
// I assume you will want to change this to random later
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) { 
  x[i] = num * (i + 1);
}
console.log(x);

function go() {
  var found=0;
  for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    if (document.getElementById("one" + i).value == x[i]) {
      found++;
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = found==x.length?x:"Sorry";
}
```

```html
<input id="one0" type="text" value="" />
<input id="one1" type="text" value="" />
<input id="one2" type="text" value="" />
<input id="one3" type="text" value="" />
<input type="button" id="verifyBtn" value="verify" onclick="go()" />
<span id="result"></span>
```

Version 2 Error if anything entered is wrong

```js
var x = [],
  num = 2;
// I assume you will want to change this to random later
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  x[i] = ""+num * (i + 1); // make string
}
console.log(x);
window.onload = function() {
  var field = document.querySelectorAll(".entry");
  for (var i = 0; i < field.length; i++) {
    field[i].onkeyup = function() { 
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = (x.indexOf(this.value) == -1)?"Sorry":this.value;
    }
  }
}

function go() {
  var field = document.querySelectorAll(".entry"),
    error = false,
    res = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < field.length; i++) {
    res += field[i].value; // string concatenation
  }
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = (res == x.join("")) ? res : "Sorry";
}
```

```html
<input class="entry" id="one0" type="text" value="" />
<input class="entry" id="one1" type="text" value="" />
<input class="entry" id="one2" type="text" value="" />
<input class="entry" id="one3" type="text" value="" />
<input type="button" id="verifyBtn" value="verify" onclick="go()" /><br/>
<span id="result">test</span>
```

Version 3 - any 1, 2, 3 or 4 entries are deemed correct if they are subpart of array, e.g. 46 is ok and so is 68 but not 26

```js
var x = [],
  num = 2;
// I assume you will want to change this to random later
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  x[i] = ""+num * (i + 1); // make string
}
console.log(x);
window.onload = function() {
  var field = document.querySelectorAll(".entry");
  for (var i = 0; i < field.length; i++) {
    field[i].onkeyup = function() { 
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = (x.indexOf(this.value) == -1)?"Sorry":this.value;
    }
  }
}

function go() {
  var field = document.querySelectorAll(".entry"),
    error = false,
    res = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < field.length; i++) {
    if (x.indexOf(field[i].value) !=-1) res.push(field[i].value); 
  }
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = (x.join(".").indexOf(res.join("."))!=-1) ? res : "Sorry";
}
```

```html
<input class="entry" id="one0" type="text" value="" />
<input class="entry" id="one1" type="text" value="" />
<input class="entry" id="one2" type="text" value="" />
<input class="entry" id="one3" type="text" value="" />
<input type="button" id="verifyBtn" value="verify" onclick="go()" /><br/>
<span id="result">test</span>
```

Comment: Hi, ur third version is almost getting there THANK U SO MUCH. The only thing is, when the user types in the numbers wrong or out of order and then clicks on the verify button, the result should just say sorry its wrong instead of showing the numbers. So the result has to be only right or wrong. But thank u soooo much for understanding my poor explanation and helping!! I really appreciate it!

Comment: I'll revisit this in 12 hours or so

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question well this should work:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="one0" type="text" value="">
    <input id="one1" type="text" value="">
    <input id="one2" type="text" value="">
    <input id="one3" type="text" value="">
    <input type="button" id="verifyBtn" value="verify" onclick="go()">

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function go() {
            var arrinputs = [];
            var arr = [2, 4, 10, 12];

            for (var x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
                var tmp = parseInt(document.getElementById("one" + x).value)
                if (!isNaN(tmp))
                    arrinputs.push(tmp);
            }
            var a = "-" + arrinputs.join('-') + "-";
            var b = "-" + arr.join('-') + "-";

            if (b.indexOf(a) != -1) {
                alert("Ok!");
            } else {
                alert("Sorry!");
            }
        }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Test 1 (check array 2, 4, 6, 8)

[image]

Returns: Corrent

Test 2 (check array 2, 4, 6, 8)

[image]

Returns: Corrent

Test 3 (check array 2, 4, 6, 8)

[image]

Returns: Sorry

Test 4 (check array 2, 4, 10, 12)

[image]

Returns: Corrent

Test 5 (check array 2, 4, 10, 12)

[image]

Returns: Sorry

Test 6 (check array 2, 4, 10, 12)

[image]

Returns: Sorry

Comment: It works better thanks but the thing is, the array is {2,4,6,8}, so even if the user inputs 4 in the first bar but then enters 6,8 in the next and clicks verify, it should say correct..

Comment: @BuffyAnne-summers You mean if frist input is '4' and second input is '68' it should be correct? Or you mean it can input comma separated number in one input for example first input '4' and second input '6,8'?

Comment: yea i meant if the first input is 4 and second is 6, and the third is 8 it should be correct

Comment: basically it has to be in order but the user can decide from where to start, If he starts from 4, we has to input 6 in the second bar and 8 in the third

Comment: leaving one bar empty

Comment: @BuffyAnne-summers I think it work just like that. Check test examples update in answer. For which test case it is not working?

Comment: thanks this was helpful but however, the problem is, I am going to be using random numbers from 1-50 and the program u showed can be applied for numbers only from 0-9 as it also can take the number 10 as 1 or 0 just cos it has 1 and 0 in it.. How do i fix that :/

Comment: @BuffyAnne-summers I updated the code and put additional test cases. It now works for those examples with larger numbers.

Comment: It still gives the same error :/ if u type 1 in the first input bar u will get the result "Ok" even tho 1 isn't in the array but perhaps it considers 10 as two different numbers

Comment: @BuffyAnne-summers you are right there are lots of special cases but I think idea for code is ok. I improved code so that works for this one (just first input is 1) :)